# Issue with unity Dreamteck.Splines

Tags: unity-game-engine, spline

A am trying to create a simple shape using Dreamteck.Splines package in unity. But after one frame in the play mode, the spline changes are reveroked.
Here is my code:

````cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Dreamteck.Splines;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SplineComputer)), RequireComponent(typeof(TubeGenerator))]
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SplineComputer splineComputer;
    private void Start()
    {
        A(); // will reset the spline for one frame
        StartCoroutine(waiter()); // will work as intended
    }
    private void A()
    {
        SplinePoint[] _points;
        Vector3[] coords;
        coords = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, -1, 0),
            new Vector3(0, -2, 0)
        };
        _points = new SplinePoint[coords.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coords.Length; i++)
        {
            SplinePoint point = new SplinePoint(coords[i]);
            point.normal = Vector3.one.normalized;
            _points[i] = point;
        }
        splineComputer.SetPoints(_points);
    }

    IEnumerator waiter()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        A();
    }
}```
If you know how to fix this issue or know of an alternative spline package, please help.
````